# Window Powershell credential request is unnecessary. How to avoid that?

Tags: powershell, ssh

The following Powershell script is prompting the credentials to the user but I am sending all the necessary information to execute the ssh session connection.

What can I change to remove the user prompt request?

```
$sshParams = @{
    Credential="user_name"    
    HostName = $sshHostName
    KeyFile = $sshIdentityFile # .pem file
}

$sshSession = New-SSHSession @sshParams

if ($null -ne $sshSession) {
    Write-Output "Connected to $sshHost"
}
else {
    $errorMessage = "SSH connection failed!"
    Write-Output $errorMessage
    throw $errorMessage
}

Write-Output "Closing SSH session..."
Remove-SSHSession -SessionId $sshSession.SessionId
```

User Prompt Request:

[image]

After click Ok with no password the connection works fine => **Promt is unnecessary!**

I need to execute the script with no Windows Prowershell credential request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the behavior you can expect from a parameter with type [`pscredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) or a parameter decorated with the [`Credential` Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/credential-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.3), if you supply a string to it it will automatically prompt you for a password:

```bash
function Test-Param {
    param([pscredential] $Credential)
}

Test-Param -Credential willPromptForPassword
```

If you want the cmdlet to not prompt for a password then you need to construct the `pscredential` beforehand and pass it as argument. For example:

```bash
function Test-Param {
    param([pscredential] $Credential)
}

$credential = [pscredential]::new(
    'doesNotPromptForPassword',
    (ConvertTo-SecureString 'thePassword' -AsPlainText -Force))

Test-Param -Credential $credential
```

As for the code you currently have, I have not personally used `New-SSHSession` but reading [the documentation](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/New-SSHSession.md#-credential) states the following:

> If a key file is used the password field is used for the Key pass phrase.

Unfortunately the documentation for this cmdlet only has 1 example and is not a particularly clear.

---

EDIT: OP has confirmed that the issue was solved by using an empty password:

```bash
$credential = [pscredential]::new(
    'user_name',
    [securestring]::new())

$sshParams = @{
    Credential = $credential
    HostName   = $sshHostName
    KeyFile    = $sshIdentityFile # .pem file
}

$sshSession = New-SSHSession @sshParams
```

Comment: based on your response, I changed the script with a fake (empty) password:

$sshParams = @{
    Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($sshUser, (ConvertTo-SecureString " " -AsPlainText -Force))
    HostName = $sshHostName
    KeyFile = $sshIdentityFile # .pem file
}

With that works fine! Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloSambucaro glad this helped, I'll add that to the answer for future readers with same issue